# Dilemma of Populating all the categories in a drop down list

Tags: php, functions, categories

A general drop down list with some generic HTML will go down like this →

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

But what If we wish to populate all the categories in this drop down?

what will we write in the `value=""` section so that we get the unique Value property.

Apart from that, I think that the loop will run such as

```
for $categories as $categorie
```

It is more of a PHP question I think and less of a WordPress. Can someone help me in taking things further?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WordPress has a specific function to do what you want, [`wp_dropdown_categories`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dropdown_categories/). By default it will fill the value field of the option with the term id, which would be unique, but there are several other options to choose from, which you can pass as an argument when calling the function.

If that doesn't satisfy you, you can even make a [walker function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker), which changes the dropdown function completely. An example is found at the bottom of the first link.

So, you can do this with one line in your template file or make it as complex as you might desire.